# возможно ли такой макет на owl

Tags: html, jquery, css, owl-carousel

пока рисовал макет по ходу сам себе ответил, но хочется услышать мнения людей
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

возможно ли сделать такой макет слайдера используя owl carousel 2
надо отобразить 3 слайда на сранице и чтоб по середине был полностью видим, а 2 по бокам были полупрозрачными и тоже были видны, а название у слайда тоже можно засунуть в этот блок, а скрываться на крайних оно будет по классу ".active"

это получается выделять крайние можно таким селектором .owl-item.active:first-child и .owl-item.active:last-child и к ним применять фильтр opacity

Comment: нужно все слайды сделать с opacity, например 0.75, а тот который по центру (с классом актив) будет с opacity : 1.

Comment: +, только получается когда в настройках делаешь 3 итема показывать, то ко всем трем класс active применяется

Answer (score 0):

```css
.owl-item.center {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100000;
}

.owl-item.center:before {
  content: "....";
  color: transparent;
}

.owl-item.center:after {
  content: "....";
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.0.0-beta.2.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.0.0-beta.2.4/assets/owl.theme.default.css">

<div class="owl-carousel">
  <div><img src="//placehold.it/300x150/936/fff/?text=1" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="//placehold.it/300x150/693/fff/?text=2" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="//placehold.it/300x150/369/fff/?text=3" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="//placehold.it/300x150/f63/fff/?text=4" alt=""></div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2//2.0.0-beta.2.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    autoplay: true,
    center: true,
    loop: true,
    nav: true,
  });
</script>
```